# do AST stays at runtime when jrubyc compilation were used?

Tags: jruby

There is ruby2ruby compiler, which can restore ruby code from AST.

I'm curious, if I compile my code with jrubyc, will someone who can evaluate his own code inside my running app be possible to get AST of my own ruby classes and then restore ruby code with ruby2ruby?

I'm using jruby 1.6.5 in ruby 1.8 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell from [this page](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCompiler), the AST is indeed present in some form in the compiled class file, and therefore it is at least theoretically recoverable by untrusted code running in the same JVM instance.  In practice, it's probably true that a Java decompiler could yield similar results anyway.